# How to use router.get and https.get together? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, router

I want to get information from the http request and send it to the frontend via the path '/ get'. I combined these 2 functions and it works but I don't think it is correct:

```
const router = express.Router();
const https = require('https');

router.get('/get', (req, res) => {
  https.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY', (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
      res.json(JSON.parse(data).explanation)
    });
  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  });
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way would be to use **Axios** to make all your http requests to external apis which you want from nodejs application. It is a promise based request making library which you can use in browser as well as on backend server.

1. Install axios using *npm install axios*
2. `axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY').then(response => res.send(response.data)).catch(error => console.log(error));`

Comment: What about path '/get'? I don't need it? Or you mean to put `axios.get...` inside `router.get...`?

Comment: Yes. You have to put this axios request inside the `router.get` because when you will call this route from frontend, then only the axios request will start and fetch data for you and send back the data to your frontend.

Answer (score 1):

No, it works fine.

But if you want another way, then use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

> you need to require `axios` and then add your request in the router.

```js
const axios = require('axios');

// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

you get more information from [here](https://github.com/axios/axios)